# pipe sequence of list of quoted segments of text In linux

Tags: linux, grep

I need to write a pipe sequence of list of quoted segments of text that contain question marks which a quoted segment of text starts and ends with a double quote character (“) and has no other double quote character.

I tried to do it like this but i dont get all the quotes:

```
cat story.txt | grep -E | sed -r "s/\n\"/ \"/
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input, expected output and your attempt to solve the problem yourself so we can help you further. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting single line `awk` script:

```
awk 'NR%2-1&&/?/{print}' RS='\"' input.txt
```